# Angular.js table mapping brain fahrt

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to front end development and am playing with angular.js (1.4.8).  In the code below, I do an http get.  I then
map the json data into a table.  I think I have a mapping problem, ie, the ng-repeat isn't pulling stuff out of the
json correctly.  Or perhaps it's something else and I'm unintentionally misleading you.  Do you see a programming
error here?

Here is the relevant html:

```
<div class="table-responsive" data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="customersCtrl">
<table class="table table-striped">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-ng-repeat="header in headers">{{header}}</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr data-ng-repeat="record in records track by $index">
                        <td>{{ record.data.day }}</td>
                        <td>{{ record.data.date }}</td>
                        <td>{{ record.data.value }}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Here is my angular file:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.init = function () {
        $http.get("https://localhost:4567/1")
            .then(function (response) {
                var json = angular.toJson(response.data.records);
                $scope.records = json;
                $scope.headers = response.data.headers;
            });
    };

    $scope.httpPost = function (journal) {
        var theJson = angular.toJson(journal);

        var successCallback = function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.postResponse = data;
        };

        var errorCallback = function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log();
        };

        $http.post('https://localhost:4567/journal', {"foo": "bar"}).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
    };

    $scope.master = {};

    $scope.update = function (journal) {
        $scope.master = angular.copy(journal);
    };

    $scope.reset = function () {
        $scope.journal = angular.copy($scope.master);
    };

    $scope.init();
    $scope.reset();
});
```

Here is the response body (json):

```
{
  "headers" : [ "day", "date", "value" ],
  "records" : [ {
    "data" : {
      "day" : "Tuesday",
      "date" : "5/3/2011",
      "value" : "2.6"
    },
    "id" : "646312cc-1931-4137-af2a-e712300b489b",
    "dateCreated" : 1453842720871,
    "dateUpdated" : 1453842720871,
    "etag" : "3bee5500-fd03-4d69-84af-8b8dc85292b0"
  }, {
    "data" : {
      "day" : "Wednesday",
      "date" : "5/4/2011",
      "value" : "2.6"
    },
    "id" : "f58eae54-6b30-4f61-b8cc-b04984a8436a",
    "dateCreated" : 1453842720871,
    "dateUpdated" : 1453842720871,
    "etag" : "29e4dc69-c118-4fad-91ae-8a1efaf9b984"
  }, {
    "data" : {
      "day" : "Thursday",
      "date" : "5/5/2011",
      "value" : "2.6"
    },
    "id" : "ebf8dba4-52a9-4e0b-a575-cda2ea29a2ea",
    "dateCreated" : 1453842720871,
    "dateUpdated" : 1453842720871,
    "etag" : "986961bb-84ff-4ac6-9f70-96827006ed87"
  } ],
  "id" : null,
  "dateCreated" : null,
  "dateUpdated" : null,
  "etag" : null
}
```

=====
As pointed out by two people, the problem was this line (I had turned json object to debug something and forgot to revert ;(

```
var json = angular.toJson(response.data.records);
```

Comment: You do not need to explicitly serialise your data to JSON before receiving or sending requests to your server unless you have customised [`$httpProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers). It sets the `Content-Type: application/json` header by default.

Comment: Why are you serializing the return value to json before assigning it to $scope.records? Serializing records means that it is now a string not an array. Try changing that line to $scope.records = response.data.records. Ng-repeat needs to be passed an array to iterate over not a string.

Comment: Thanks to both of you - that was the problem.  I am coding alone and that's the kind of thing that pairing with another person would have caught.  I knew I was doing something dumb and just missed it ... hence the title "brain fahrt" ... I knew it was something like this.  You probably saved me a good bit of time.  @Miqid, you answered first, so feel free to post and I'll credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular's [`$httpProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers) automatically adds the `Content-Type: application/json` header to all outgoing service requests made by your application.

In addition, it will also automatically deserialise responses using a JSON parser if a JSON-like response is detected.

As such, there is no need to use functions like `angular.toJson()` to do the JSON conversion yourself unless you have overridden the default provider behaviour somewhere.

Glad that helped. :-)

Comment: While a little embarassing to publish my brain fahrt's, I realize everyone has them from time to time.  I've at times pointed out obvious things to brilliant programmers.  Thanks for being my code buddy ;)